# RabbitMQ Pub/Sub: Closing the last consumer closes the publisher's channel/model. Why?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, rabbitmq, publish-subscribe

I'm using .Net RabbitMQ for some pub/sub (publisher/subscriber) code.  Everything works fine until I start closing consumers.  The consumers handle the published data properly until I close the last consumer.  After all consumers, I open a new consumer, but nothing happens.  The application opens, but it doesn't receive any data from the publisher.

I checked the publisher code and found out that when the last consumer closes, its channel's *IsOpen* property becomes false.  I don't know if there is some setting to keep a channel open even after its consumer is closed.

Here is my publisher code:
**EDIT** I originally pasted the wrong code.

And here is my consumer code:

```
public MyConsumer
{
private readonly ConnectionFactory _factory;
private readonly IConnection _connection;
private readonly IModel _channel;
private readonly Timer _timer;

private SubscriptionConsumerType(string ipAddress, string exchangeName, TimeSpan tsPullCycle)
{
    //set up connection
    this._factory = new ConnectionFactory();
    this._factory.HostName = ipAddress;
    this._connection = this._factory.CreateConnection();
    this._channel = this._connection.CreateModel();

    //set up and bind the exchange
    this._channel.ExchangeDeclare(exchangeName, "fanout", false, true, new Dictionary<string, object>());
    string queueName = this._channel.QueueDeclare().QueueName;
    this._channel.QueueBind(queueName, exchangeName, "");

    //start consuming
    QueueingBasicConsumer consumer = new QueueingBasicConsumer(this._channel);
    this._channel.BasicConsume(queueName, true, consumer);

    //periodically check for new messages from the publisher
    this._timer = new Timer(new TimerCallback(this.TimerStep), consumer, tsPullCycle, tsPullCycle);
}

public void Dispose()
{
    if (this._timer != null)
        this._timer.Dispose();

    if (this._channel != null)
    {
        this._channel.Close();
        this._channel.Dispose();
    }

    if (this._connection != null)
    {
        this._connection.Close();
        this._connection.Dispose();
    }
}
}
```

Right now, my workaround for this is to always have a consumer window open somewhere.  Ideally though, I want my publisher to run regardless of the number of consumer windows open.  Thanks.

**Edit** Oops, I pasted the wrong producer code.  Here is that:

```
private SubscriptionBroadcastType(string ipAddress, string exchangeName)
{
    this._factory = new ConnectionFactory();
    this._factory.HostName = ipAddress;
    this._connection = this._factory.CreateConnection();
    this._channel = this._connection.CreateModel();

    this._exchangeName = exchangeName;
    this._channel.ExchangeDeclare(exchangeName, SubscriptionBroadcastType.BROADCAST, SubscriptionBroadcastType.DURABLE, SubscriptionBroadcastType.AUTO_DELETE, new Dictionary<string, object>());
}

public void BroadcastMessage(string message)
{
    lock (this._syncroot) //protect _channel
    {
        if (this._channel.IsOpen)
            this._channel.BasicPublish(this._exchangeName, "", null, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you may have something fundamentally wrong here.  Please check that you have published the correct code.  As I read it you have a producer creating a specific named queue and publishing directly to the queue.  You have a consumer creating a specific named exchange and then creating a new queue which is dynamically named and binding that to the exchange.  You are then reading from this queue, but it can't be the queue that you originally published to.

I would fix your code first to add create an exchange in your publisher code with a specific name that you have access to in your consumer code.   This line will appear in producer thread instead of the queue declare line:

```
this._channel.ExchangeDeclare(exchangeName, "fanout", false, true, new Dictionary<string, object>());
```

Then you will need to publish to that exchange so instead of the line that publishes to the queue change that to:

```
this._channel.BasicPublish(exchangeName, "", this._basicProperties, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message));
```

Your consumer should be set up fine to receive these messages from the queue as it is.  See if that helps with your problem.

Comment: You're right, I pasted the wrong producer code.  Thank you for pointing that out.  I edited my original post to fix this.